# Using PrintWriter to print a string to a text file, but when I open the text file it is empty

Tags: java, file, text, printing, is-empty

I'm using PrintWriter in Java to try to write some Strings to a text file, however when I open the text file it is empty.

Here is my code:

```
public void save(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException{

    PrintWriter out1 = new PrintWriter("aSB.txt");
    out1.println("The Pupil's information is listed below:");
    for (Pupil pup : Pupils) {
       out1.println(pup.getFirstName() + " " + pup.getLastName());
    }
    out1.println("End");
    out1.println("The Club's information is listed below:");
    for (Club clu : Clubs) {
       out1.println(clu.getName());
    }
    out1.close();   
}
```

Why is the filename empty?

Comment: Check the file aSB.txt, maybe the missing text is there..

Comment: How do you start the program? Perhaps you would be surprised about what it considers its working directory, which is where the file ought to be.

Comment: try specifying an absolute path (related to what Henrik says above).

Comment: Pupils and Clubs are empty arrays.  Print their sizes before iterating through them.  You'll see they are zero.  Also, give the full path of the file: "C:\\aSB.txt".  The file might not be saving where you think.

Comment: @EricLeschinski: Even if the arrays are empty, the file should still at least contain the lines _"The Pupils's/Club's information is listed below:"_ and _"End"_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kevin said, maybe directory issues. Try to specify the full path see what happens.

Something like:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("c:/asb.txt");
```

Alternatively, see [here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-write/java-writer-example.shtml)

quite possibly the array are empty

Comment: Yes, specifying the path worked! The only reason that I did not do that to start with was because I read in Big Java that the default path meant that it would look in the src for the txt file. Thanks for your advice guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try to catch FileNotFoundException and see if you have error creating the file.
Also try catching SecurityException. 
If not try using FileOutputStream. It is really easy to use it
Good luck!